# (Python) Write string to CSV with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, utf-8, export-to-csv

I have data in the database and I want to export it to CSV file.
The data is in Japanese and for further use, I need it to be encoded in UTF-8

This is my script to get the data and write in the CSV file

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

import sys
import csv

query = 'SELECT * FROM `images-data`'

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234',
                                 host='127.0.0.1',
                                 database='sotsuken-test-db')
    cur=cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    result=cur.fetchall()

    c = csv.writer(open("db-data.csv","w"))
    for row in result:
        c.writerow(row)



except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cnx.close()
```

I can create the CSV file, and the data is exported in UTF-8, but my CSV file's data was like this:

```
1,b'\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x94\xe3\x81\x8a\xe3\x81\x96\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99'
```

In my research I found that my data was written in byte object (may be I'm wrong here). I need the data to be written in UTF-8 without `b''`

I know that I can use `decode("UTF-8")` to make it into the string, but I cannot apply that to `csv.writerow`

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: why not use csv.DictWriter command, you decode ('UTF-8') your individual cell values and using DictWriter you could write to specific columns in your csv file

Comment: Thank you for a nice, consize, well written question following about all guidelines for new questions/on topic/mvce

Comment: @SuryaTej How would `DictWriter` solve this any better than `writer`? Sure, it's nicer for _other_ reasons, if you know what your columns are, but it doesn't change the fact that some of those columns are `bytes`.

Comment: As a side note, you don't actually need to do `fetchall` here. You can just iterate `for row in cur:` and the cursor should give you one row at a time, buffering up as many rows in memory as it thinks would be most efficient, instead of reading them all into memory no matter what. Also, it's usually a bad idea to not close files you opened for writing, either with a `close()` call or a `with` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`csv.writer.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) just takes a list of whatever you've got,<sup>1</sup> calls `str` on each element, and puts them together into a line of CSV.

So, if what you've got is `bytes` objects, then it's going to call `str` on them and get strings like `b'\xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88\xe3\x81\xa7\xe3\x81\x94\xe3\x81\x8a\xe3\x81\x96\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99'`.

The solution is to give it strings.

---

The simplest way to do it is by decoding those `bytes`:

> I know that I can use `decode("UTF-8")` to make it into the string, but I cannot apply that to `csv.writerow`

Sure you can. I don't know what your columns are, so I'll make up my own example:

```
for image_id, image_name in result:
    c.writerow([image_id, image_name.decode('UTF-8')])
```

That's really all there is to it.

---

What if your code has absolutely no idea what the columns in the database are? Well, in that case, you have to get a little bit clever. As long as we know that all of the `bytes` columns are really Unicode text in disguise as UTF-8, you can just switch on the type:

```
for row in result:
    textrow = [col.decode('UTF-8') if isinstance(col, bytes) else col for col in row]
    csv.writerow(textrow)
```

That's a bit ugly, but reading `*` from a database where you have no idea what the columns are is inherently an ugly problem.

---

However, there's probably a much better solution.

MySQL Connector/Python turns all `CHAR`, `TEXT`, and similar columns into Unicode `str` values by default.<sup>2</sup> But `BINARY`, `BLOB`, and similar columns are always returned as `bytes`.

If this column is meant to represent Unicode text, set it to a text type instead of a binary one in the database. Then you won't have a problem in the first place—in this script, or in any other tools.

---

<sub>1. Actually, it appears to be illegal to call it with a list of anything but strings and numbers, according to the docs. But practically, it takes anything at all; it just doesn't do anything very *useful* with any types besides strings and numbers…</sub>

<sub>2. That is, unless you explicitly pass it a [`use_unicode=False`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) in the `connect` call or similarly set it elsewhere.</sub>